# How to get a copy of the log output of the current request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

In a Rails 4 application, inside a controller action, I wish to get my hands on all log output created *during the current request*. I especially wish to keep *all* log output, no matter what level has been set (i.e., if the logger is set not to write `:debug` to the logfile, then I still want to have log output with the `:debug` level handed to me).

One solution would be to use a `before` filter to monkeypatch the `Rails.logger`, i.e. `Rails.logger.extend(MyLoggerMemoryStoreWrapper)`, where that wrapper overrides the `#add` method of the logger, to collect any log output in an array for eventual consumption.

But is there a better way? I.e., some fashion in which I can just configure that with a one-liner? Is there some support for cascading loggers or something like that in Rails? I can *not* change the lines where the actual logging happens (i.e., the log will still be written with `Rails.logger.info 'xyz'` and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *configure* a different logger, once, in your application setup. What that logger does is then entirely within your control, so it can provide `clear_buffer` and `contents_of_buffer` methods, it can operate at the `:debug` level, and it can choose to both record messages in that buffer and pass them along to a second logger (which might be configured for a higher level, and to write to a file as usual).